# Finding the limit of $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}[(a+\frac{1}{n})^{2}+(a+\frac{2}{n})^{2}+...+(a+\frac{n-1}{n})^{2}] $

Tags: limits

Here's my try:  
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}[(a+\frac{1}{n})^{2}+(a+\frac{2}{n})^{2}+...+(a+\frac{n-1}{n})^{2}] = $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}[\frac{1}{n}(a^{2}+\frac{2a}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}})+\frac{1}{n}(a^{2}+\frac{4a}{n}+\frac{4}{n^{2}})+...+\frac{1}{n}(a^{2}+\frac{2a(n-1)}{n}+\frac{(n-1)^{2}}{n^{2}})]= $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}[n\frac{a^{2}}{n}+\frac{2a+4a+...+2a(n-1)}{n^{2}}+\frac{1^2+2^2+...+(n-1)^{2}}{n^{3}}]= $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}[a^{2}+\frac{2a(1+2+...+(n-1))}{n^{2}}+\frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{3n^{3}}]= a^{2}+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}[\frac{2a(n-1)n}{2n^2}+\frac{2n^{2}-3n+1}{3n^2}]= a^{2}+a+\frac{2}{3}$

but the last fraction should be $\frac{1}{3}$, not $\frac{2}{3}$, Anybody can point out where's my mistake?

---

2 mistakes pointed out by user kingW3, thank you

The CORRECT solution for other newcomers like me:
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}[(a+\frac{1}{n})^{2}+(a+\frac{2}{n})^{2}+...+(a+\frac{n-1}{n})^{2}] = $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}[\frac{1}{n}(a^{2}+\frac{2a}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}})+\frac{1}{n}(a^{2}+\frac{4a}{n}+\frac{4}{n^{2}})+...+\frac{1}{n}(a^{2}+\frac{2a(n-1)}{n}+\frac{(n-1)^{2}}{n^{2}})]= $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}[\mathbf{(n-1)}\frac{a^{2}}{n}+\frac{2a+4a+...+2a(n-1)}{n^{2}}+\frac{1^2+2^2+...+(n-1)^{2}}{n^{3}}]= $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}[a^{2}+\frac{2a(1+2+...+(n-1))}{n^{2}}+\frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{\mathbf{6}n^{3}}]= a^{2}+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}[\frac{2a(n-1)n}{2n^2}+\frac{2n^{2}-3n+1}{\mathbf{6}n^2}]= a^{2}+a+\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Recall the formula for the sum of squares,there is a mistake + I think that it is $(n-1)\frac{a^2}{n}$ in the 3rd line

Comment: Thanks man, that was a really stupid mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{\color{red}{6}}\quad?$$

**Remark:** You can simply find the result using the Riemann sum.

Comment: +1 for the riemann suggestion; it is $\int_a^{a+1} x^2 dx = \frac{(a+1)^3-a^3}{3}$.